# Order by before group by in subquery working in mysql 5.5 but not in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem when use Order By and Group By in a query string.

There is a table careers that contains data as shown below:

```
id   se_id   enrollment_start
-------------------------
1    1       2005-07-01
2    2       2008-10-12
3    2       2006-05-09
4    1       2016-11-10
5    3       2015-02-04
6    3       2010-08-11
```

I want to get se_id which has highest enrollment_start.

This is a sql statement I used. It works in mysql 5.5 but not in mysql 5.7:

```
SELECT 
    tmp.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        careers
    ORDER BY enrollment_start DESC) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.se_id
```

This is groupwise maximum problem, and there are many topics cover about it. But I don't want the answer for that problem, I want to know why above statement woking in mysql 5.5 but it doesn't work in mysql 5.7 and is there any method to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: if work in 5.5 was pure luck. that shouldnt work.

Comment: I don't think so, I tested many times, it always work like a charm, even though I know subquerey returns unordered result

Comment: see the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Drew: i set sql_mode = '' and still get nothing different

Comment: All I can say is write proper sql. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: and stay away from `select *` ... that is normally a disaster waiting to happen with any group by. Also pretty funny when done by people with unions and different tables (diff col counts). It is just sloppy programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *to get se_id which has highest enrollment_start.* use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    careers
ORDER BY enrollment_start DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to get many rows, not one